# Corrupt PDF files When File is written to the response

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

So i have a PDF file on my server, i can open it up and it looks fine.

What I'm trying to achieve is to load a PDF from an unmanaged delphi DLL to an UnmanagedStream in ASP.NET

I then try to serve the file with this code!

```
        UnmanagedMemoryStream memoryStream;

        ReportDLL.getStream(out streamPointer, out bufferSize, true);        
        memoryStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream((Byte*)streamPointer, bufferSize);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);

        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.pdf");
        response.OutputStream.Write(reader.ReadBytes(bufferSize), 0, bufferSize);

        // End the response to prevent further work by the page processor.
        response.End()
```

Comment: A quick try would be to add `resonse.Flush();` before you end it.

Comment: I already try. it did'nt work !

Comment: Some clients require a content length header.